# Can i create a new zone for my sub-submenu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm actually making a menu for my homework, but I'm not really good at JS, and I want to extend my sub-submenu with an hover on a new "window"

I already tried to do it only in CSS/HTML but thats didn't work

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqBRGZ

```
<body>
  <div class="area-x"></div>
  <nav class="main-menu" id="accordian">
     <div>
        <ul>
           <li id="menu1">
              <h3><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Client</span></h3>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li id="menu3">
                          <a href="#">test11111111111</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a>
                    <ul>
                       <li id="menu3">
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                          <a href="#">test1</a>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </li>
```

I think I can do what I want with javascript, but I didn't find on the internet what I want, tuto or something like that, so if you can help me and explain, that's will be great.

Comment: Are you able to bring your codepen code into a stack overflow snippet?

Comment: You mean like a submenu in a submenu?

Comment: @xmaster yeah like that, and its with an hover, thats open a "new" window for select something

Comment: @Fidio check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown)

Comment: @xmaster thats what i already do, but, i want another sub-menu, like, on "link 1" imagine you have a hover who some sub menu appear too

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h) out

Comment: so i tried something, but thats only work with click, and i want a hover, i tried to change "click" by hover, but thats change all my menu on hover, and i have some click to open some sub-menu

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:150);

.fa-2x {
 font-size: 2em;
}

.fa {
 position: relative;
 display: table-cell;
 width: 60px;
 height: 36px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size:20px;
}

.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
 width:250px;
 overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
 background: #1f67f1;
 border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 height:100%;
 left:0;
 width:60px;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
 transition:width .05s linear;
 -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
 z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
 margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>h3 {
 margin-top: 0px;
 position:relative;
 display:table;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 border-spacing:0;
 color:white;
  font-family: arial;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
 -webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
 transition:all .1s linear;
 margin: 0px;
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
 position:relative;
 display:table-cell;
 width:60px;
 height:36px;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;
 font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
 position:relative;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 width:190px;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
 overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
 overflow-y:auto;
 overflow:visible;
}

h3:hover,h3:focus {
 text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
 -webkit-user-select:none;
 -moz-user-select:none;
 -ms-user-select:none;
 -o-user-select:none;
 user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
 outline:0;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>h3,.dropdown-menu>li>h3:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>h3:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>h3,.dropdown-menu>.active>h3:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>h3:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover h3,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active h3 {
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #1f67f1;
}

.area {
 float: left;
 background: #e2e2e2;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#accordian ul ul {
 display: none;
}

#accordian li.active ul {
 display: block;
}

#menu2 {
 margin-left: 110px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

#menu1:hover h3 {
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#5fa2db;
}

#menu2 a:hover {
    color:#fff;
 background-color:#5fa2db; 
}

#menu2 ul li{
 position: relative;
}

#menu1 ul li:hover > ul{
 left: -100px;
 top:0px;
}

#menu2 ul li:hover > a{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#5fa2db; 
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
}

#menu1 li:hover ul ul {
 display:none;
}

#menu1 li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}

#menu3 a {
    display:block;
 margin-left:200px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
 overflow: visible;
}

.main-menu #menu3 a:hover{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#5fa2db;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
   <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8' />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="icons/css/unicons.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script>
         function afficheMenu(obj){
         var idMenu     = obj.id;
         var idSousMenu = 'sous' + idMenu;
         var sousMenu   = document.getElementById(idSousMenu);
         /*****************************************************/
         /** si le sous-menu correspondant au menu cliqué    **/
         /** est caché alors on l'affiche, sinon on le cache **/
         /*****************************************************/
         if(sousMenu.style.display == "none"){
         sousMenu.style.display = "block";
         }
         else{
         sousMenu.style.display = "none";
         }
         }
      </script>   
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="area-x"></div>
      <nav class="main-menu" id="accordian">
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Client</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li id="menu3">
                              <a href="#">test11111111111</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li id="menu3">
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li class="has-subnav" id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Conducteur</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li id="menu3">
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                              <a href="#">test1</a>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li class="has-subnav" id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-bus fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Autocar</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Devis</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Billet</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-file fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Bons Factures</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-file-text fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Factures Diverses</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-binoculars fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Recherche avancée...</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Export des ventes</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Saisie des Règlements</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Gestion des bordereaux</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Factures non soldées</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Export des Règlements</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Export des bordereaux</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Modèles Hebdomadaires</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-tasks fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Lignes Règulières</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Affichage Planning</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>

               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Statistiques</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               
               <li id="menu1">
                  <h3><i class="fa fa-binoculars fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Recherche avancée by evnt</span></h3>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#" id="menu2">test</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               </ul>
         </div>
         <ul class="logout">
            <li>     <h3><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>  <span class="nav-text">Quitter Carmagic</span></h3></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
     $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
     if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
     {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
     }
    })
   })
</script>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#menu2").hover(function(){
         
      })
   })
</script>
```

i dont know why, but my js didnt work on stack overflow